How to make table cell force width in full width table
I want that my one column be a fixed size, for example 50px, and other columns would be free.
For example I have such table structure 
I want that my first column would be fixed on 50px, nevermind what size of screen would be and other columns will stretch out. In css I have
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid $border;
  border-radius: 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;

In html I have such table stucture
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr><th>content</th</tr>
     ...
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>content</td</tr>
      ...
   </tbody>
</table>


Here you can get code of my real table - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-table-lxzyj6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A189%2C33

Use with th:first-child, td:first-child


        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th:first-child, td:first-child {
            width: 50px;
        }
        th, td {
            height: 50px;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Content 1</td>
                <td>Content 2</td>
                <td>Content 3</td>
                <td>Content 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Content 5</td>
                <td>Content 6</td>
                <td>Content 7</td>
                <td>Content 8</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>




Unfortunately it dosen't work for me

Maybe because my real table more complicated

Try to bring here as much real code as possible and we will try to help

the real table is made with react-table. But i'll try to bring some more code

check the comment, a bring some real code
